# Burnt CD keeps coming up unreadable at install

Tags: grub2

I have burnt a CD for Ubuntu 12.04.4 in my ASUS laptop and have gotten an error that a file is not-readable. I burnt an alternate CD and then a DVD to see if this was an individual media error. It was not. It must be an error with the ISO file.

I want to have the grub option of selecting either windows 8.1 or Ubuntu come up. I am running this from the UEFI selection in Windows 8.1.

Does anyone know if this online provided iso file is corrupt. or a better iso file to install, or maybe I should use a different version of ubuntu or kbuntu?

Comment: Sometimes, Secure Boot will cause this error. Try disabling it in your BIOS and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Others will come along with better info probably, but here is what I know...

Make sure the CD Drive laser is clean and dust free, clean the DVD / CD, turn your PC off so it can chill out, boot directly from shutdown into the OS with the burning software (restarts mess with (dual, triple, etc) Linux/Windows partitions.

Try burning at the slowest speed possible. Use session or disk at once.

THEN, make sure your ISO has the correct MD5sum hash #. There should be a file either with your ISO or in the website directory you found it. Compare that number to the ones found here by pasting it into the "FIND" box: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

I just spent a good day trying figuring out why one of my burned ISO DVD images kept giving me an [ERRNO 5] Input/Output Error. It said there was something wrong with my Hard Disk or DVD but really it was because the ISO didn't have the right "data integrity" or what have you, as shown by the inconsistencies between its MD5sum and the official ones on that Ubuntu page.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if this is your first time with Ubuntu or any Linux distro, please know that the extra .4 in the title can make all the difference when it comes to hardware / driver compatibility. The extra .4 there means your Ubuntu 12.04 has the same Kernel Stack and Xorg stack as Ubuntu 13.10, those being 3.11 and 1.14 (?) respectively. 12.04.0 has kernel 3.2 and X server 1.11, I believe.

So, if you are trying to install a program that requires a kernel no higher than 3.0 or something, you could be screwed. I spent ages trying to figure out why my FGLRX drivers were not working and that is why.